# Can parameters be used within extra files?

Tags: loadrunner

I am calling a REST service, and I would like to specify an external file for my JSON body like below:

```
web_custom_request(
        "LOGIN", 
        "URL=myserver.com/sample/rest/url/login",
        "Method=PUT",
        "Resource=0",
        "EncType=application/json",
        "Mode=HTTP",
        "BodyFilePath=login.json",
        LAST);
```

The contents of 'login.json' are:

```
{
  "password": "{password}",
  "username": "{username}",
}
```

At the moment, this does not work. The parameters are never substituted, leading to a literal JSON request containing a user name of "{username}". Is there a way to use parameterization to alter the contents of files like this within LoadRunner? I would like to keep using files to store the body of my JSON requests, because there are some requests which are absurdly long and it isn't very readable to just put them in the script as a C-compatible escaped string.

Answer (score 0):

Read the contents of the file into a buffer.  Be sure to allow the size of your buffer to include the parameter names plus whatever amount they will be expanded to to include the actual values.

Use `lr_eval_string(The_variable_name_of_your_buffer_containing_your_json_body)` to ensure that the items in durly braces are evaluated as parameters instead of just regular strings.